# Python - Bug in code

Tags: python

This might be an easy one, but I can't spot where I am making the mistake.

I wrote a simple program to read words from a wordfile (don't have to be dictionary words), sum the characters and print them out from lowest to highest. (PART1)

Then, I wrote a small script after this program to filter and search for only those words which have only alphabetic, characters in them. (PART2)

While the first part works correctly, the second part prints nothing. I think the error is at the line 'print ch' where a character of a list converted to string is not being printed. Please advise what could be the error

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# compares two words and checks if word1 has smaller sum of chars than word2
def cmp_words(word_with_sum1,word_with_sum2):
    (word1_sum,__)=word_with_sum1
    (word2_sum,__)=word_with_sum2
    return word1_sum.__cmp__(word2_sum)

# PART1
word_data=[]
with open('smalllist.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        word=l.strip()
        word_sum=sum(map(ord,(list(word))))
        word_data.append((word_sum,word))

word_data.sort(cmp_words)

for index,each_word_data in enumerate(word_data):
    (word_sum,word)=each_word_data

#PART2
# we only display words that contain alphabetic characters and numebrs
valid_characters=[chr(ord('A')+x) for x in range(0,26)] + [x for x in    range(0,10)]

# returns true if only alphabetic characters found 
def only_alphabetic(word_with_sum):
    (__,single_word)=word_with_sum

    map(single_word.charAt,range(0,len(single_word)))

    for ch in list(single_word):
        print ch    # problem might be in this loop -- can't see ch
        if not ch in valid_characters:
            return False
    return True

valid_words=filter(only_alphabetic,word_data)
for w in valid_words:
    print w
```

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: FYI, using `cmp` functions is deprecated, slower, and less intuitive than using `key` functions for sorting. You could completely drop `cmp_words`, add an import for `from operator import itemgetter` and change `word_data.sort(cmp_words)` to `word_data.sort(key=itemgetter(0))` to get the same results, less verbosely and faster. Also, `str` are iterables of their characters, you don't need to wrap in `list` to iterate them, so, for example, `sum(map(ord,(list(word))))` could simplify to `sum(map(ord, word))` or even more efficiently if less obviously, in Py2 you could do `sum(bytearray(word))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `charAt` does not exist in python.

You can use directly: 'for ch in my_word`.

Notes:

1. you can use the builtin `str.isalnum()` for you test
2. valid_characters contains only the uppercase version of the alphabet

Comment: Shouldn't a NameError be thrown in that case?

Comment: on my system (python 2.7) it throws 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'charAt'

Comment: NameError are for cases when a variable is not defined/found

Comment: Thanks valentin! Good pickup on valid_characters -- that is a mistake. fixed it. 

I actually had "for ch in single_word": that didn't work... so I had to change to list(word).  Reverting to form without list doesn't appear to have helped =( 

Btw, I have noticed that when I "print ch", it displays numbers and special chars whereas there are characters in my wordlists:w":::,

Comment: `print ch` is used during filtering, so it will shows all characters

Comment: @valentin You are right. I just wondered why John didn't get any errors (and if that means that the function is never called)